# trying to understand protocols and delegates in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to wrap my head around protocols and delegates, but seems to be having some issues. I have 2 ViewControllers that I'm trying to pass data from. ViewController A has a text field that I want to be optionally populated from ViewController B. So there is a button on ViewController A that segues you over to ViewController B This is how I have B set up.

```
 protocol AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate{
    var playersName:String? { set get }
}

class B-Controller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var addPlayerDelegate:AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    ..etc

    }
```

I'm using this code in my viewControllers B class to dismiss the currentView when a cell is selected

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        println("did select")
        let cell = playerTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        addPlayerDelegate?.playersName? = "New Name"

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
```

It's not allowing me to set the players Name property inside the protocol here. It keeps returning me Nil when I check it from ViewController A.

View Controller A looks like this:

```
    class A-ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate{

var addPlayerDelegate:AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

//then I'm just trying to print out the new name the was set in ViewController B

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
println("this is the selected players name \(addPlayerDelegate?.playersName)") - returns nil
```

}

I'm sure I'm not fully understanding something, but I feel that I just keep reading and trying out examples only to end back up here where I started from.

//************************* UPDATE  *************************//

I'm going to try and simplify my set up. I have 2 View Controllers, VC-A, and VC-B.

VC-A has a text field and a button. VC-B has a tableview. I want the option to have the textField to be populated from the cell.text from CB-B, but only if the user taps the button to view VC-B. So the first time that VC-A loads, it should being back nil from my playersName string from the protocol, because VC-B has never been called as of yet. But once the user taps the button inside VC-A to view VB-B and then selected a cell, which would dismiss VC-B and populate the playersName string inside the protocol on the VC-B class, then I'm using the viewWillAppear method to check to see if playersName has been set and if so use it. Here is my updated code from the help you have given me.

VC-A

```
class FirstViewController: AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate{

    var playersName:String?

    let svc = LookUpViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        svc.addPlayerDelegate = self
    }
}
```

VC-B

```
protocol AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate{
    var playersName:String? { set get }
}


class LookUpViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var addPlayerDelegate: AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate?  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = playerTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        addPlayerDelegate?.playersName = "Ziggy"


        println("the name to be pass is \(addPlayerDelegate?.playersName)")

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
```

It seems that I'm still getting nil even when I got back to VC-A from VC-B. All I want is to be able to get some data (string) from VC-B and use it in VC-A, but only after the user uses the VC-B class. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

You have shown that in the BController you have a property `addPlayerDelegate`:

```
var addPlayerDelegate:AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate?
```

And you have shown that in the BController you talk to that property:

```
addPlayerDelegate?.playersName? = "New Name"
```

But you have not shown that at any point in the lifetime of this controller, its `addPlayerDelegate` property is ever *set* to anything. For example I would want to see code like this:

```
someBController.addPlayerDelegate = someAController
```

If that doesn't happen, then that property remains at its initial value of nil.

---

Another problem with your code is that this line makes no sense:

```
class A-ViewController : // {
    var addPlayerDelegate:AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

The AController doesn't *need* this property. They don't *both* need delegates! What the AController needs is a `playersName` property. Without it, it doesn't conform to the AddPlayersViewControllerDelegate protocol. In fact, I'm surprised that without that property your code even compiles. Are you sure you are reporting it correctly?

Comment: By the way, here's a downloadable example project that shows the protocol / delegate pattern fully and correctly in Swift: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch06p264presentedViewController/ch19p601presentedViewController I suggest you just copy it slavishly until you understand it.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your help, I have been looking over your example files and I still had some questions, I updated my question above and put in the new code that I am using, no errors but still only getting back nil each time.

Comment: So you do not even understand classes and instances, it seems. The LookupViewController referred to in the first code is not the one that runs the second code.

Comment: No I understand classes and instances..what would make you say that? I'm trying to simplify my code so so that it's not so much to look through. At a really high level, I just want to grab a var from VC-B and use it in VC-A, but I know the first time VC-B will not exist yet, until the user clicks on that button to init that View. That's ok, I can check for nil from that var.

Comment: Try to remember that you are the one who is having trouble here. "I'm sure I'm not fully understanding something." That is true. I'm telling you what it is. You don't understand that each time you instantiate a class you get a _different_ instance. If you did, you would not say `let svc = LookUpViewController()` and `svc.addPlayerDelegate = self` in the expectation of something meaningful happening. This `svc` is not the same as the LookUpViewController that will appear when "the user taps the button to view VC-B", so you have still not established a line of communication from B to A.

Comment: Hey Matt, sorry if that sounded rude or defensive not what I was going for at all. I was under the impression that once a class is instantiated that it's put on to the pile and just added and removed, thus the reason I thought ViewDidLoad is only called once, maybe I have been thinking about this all wrong....

Comment: "maybe I have been thinking about this all wrong" Well, the way you've been thinking about it is not causing even the simplest program to succeed, so, yeah, maybe, eh?